# writing to a text file with proper allign

Tags: python, text, file-io, string-formatting, rewriting

What is the best to write to a text file I was trying

```
>>> a = ['short', 'longline', 'verylongline']
>>> b = [123, 2347575, 8]
>>> ww = open("write_proper.txt", "w")
>>> for each in xrange(3):
...    ww.write("%s\t%s\n" % (a[each], b[each]))
...
>>> ww.close()
```

which produced output:

```
short   123
longline    2347575
verylongline    8
```

Is there any way where contents can be properly spaced to look pretty:

```
short           123
longline        2347575
verylongline    8
```

So that it considers the longest length of contents in the 1st column and places the 2nd column acccordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the field width *a priori*, then you can include the field width in your format specification:

```
ww.write("%-12s\t%s\n" % (a[each], b[each]))
```

If you want it to be data sensitive, try:

```
awidth = max(len(x) for x in a)
...
ww.write("%-*s\t%s\n" % (awidth, a[each], b[each]))
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Answer (score 0):

A bit more advanced solution:

```
a = ['short', 'longline', 'verylongline']
b = [123, 2347575, 8]

items = zip(a, b)
awidth = max(len(item) for item in a)
line_format = '{label:<{awidth}} {value}\n'

with open('write_proper.txt', 'w') as f:
    for label, value in items:
        line = line_format.format(**locals())
        f.write(line)
```